# If $f^n$ is a contraction, is $f^m(x)$ a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: general-topology

I wonder if $f: X\rightarrow X$ from the metric space $X$ to itself is such that there exists $n>1$ such that $f^n$ is a contraction, then it is true that for any point $x\in X$, $(f^m(x))_m$ is a Cauchy sequence? I think of this question when I was doing an exercise that asks to show that if $X$ is complete, then $f$ has a unique fixed point. I was able to solve this exercise but still curious about the answer of my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you assume that $X$ is bounded?

Comment: @Yanko no, but I am interested in the situation in both cases.

Comment: Just to make sure, by contraction you mean $d(f(x),f(y))<\lambda d(x,y)$ where $0<\lambda <1$?

Comment: @Yanko yes, with the same $\lambda$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @Yanko Thanks for your answer but the hypothesis is only that $f$ composed with itself $n$ times is contraction. We don’t know if $f$ is a contraction itself do we?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f^n$ is a contraction, we can find $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that $d(f^nx,f^ny)\leq\lambda d(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Fix $x\in X$, and we can partition $(f^mx)_m$ into $n$ subsequences $(x_k(r)=f^{nk+r}x)_k$ for $r=0,1,\dots,n-1$.  We know each $(x_k(r))_k$ is Cauchy because $f^n$ is a contraction.  Let $\operatorname{diam}\{f^mx\mid m\geq 0\}=\Delta$ (this is finite because we have finitely many Cauchy sequences).  Then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{diam}\{f^mx\mid m\geq m_0=nk+r\}
&\leq\operatorname{diam}\{f^mx\mid m\geq nk\}\\
&\leq\lambda^k\Delta\to 0
\end{align}
as $k\to\infty$ (equivalently $m_0\to\infty$), so $(f^mx)_m$ is Cauchy.